# Electron+React Push Notification With Web-Push

Tags: notifications, electron, web-push

I tried to use web-push with Electron + React, and got this error

```
 DOMException: Registration failed - push service not available
```

I did everything according to this [article](https://medium.com/@seladir/how-to-implement-web-push-notifications-in-your-node-react-app-9bed79b53f34)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Electron doesn't support WebPush notifications out of the box, because this is not part of Chromium itself. More details [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6697).

As an alternative solution, you can use [Pushy](https://pushy.me/) (paid) or this beautiful library — [electron-push-receiver](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver). I am using electron-push-receiver myself and it works like a charm with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: can you share the example with the electron-push-receiver with the latest electron version?